# Visual Studio 2010 row lines

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

How can I remove row-lines from visual studio?  At the moment it looks like this:

```
---------try
-----------{
----------------liste_msg.Text = "File Uploded!";
----------------con.Close();
------------}
--------catch (Exception)
-----------{
----------------liste_msg.Text = "File cant uploaded.";
-----------}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to toggle it.

It's also under the menu bars in `Edit > Advanced > View White Space`.